# Can you delete a FILE object created from fopen?

Tags: c++, fopen

While investigating a crash, I came across this code:

```
FILE * RejectFile = fopen("filename", "a+");
// other code happens
delete RejectFile;
```

My understanding is that you only call `delete` on objects that were created by `new`. Granted some of this old code is really bad so it's likely this is wrong, but I'm not sure. Is this valid code?

Comment: Should be a FILE * rather than FILE and no, you should not do a delete.  my understanding is that the FILE pointer provided by fopen() is a run time thing that is owned by the run time.  may just be a pointer to a statically allocated area of memory that is part of the run time environment.

Comment: Ah yes, it actually is a FILE *, I just copied it wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, this is not valid.  Only ever use `delete` on pointers obtained via `new`.  What happens here is undefined behavior; it might work, it might crash, it might output garbage, it might start playing some music...

You need to use `fclose()` to destroy the file handle.

Comment: Well phrased, given that it might accidentally work right depending on platform and stdlib.

Comment: close and release the file resource may be a more appropriate term rather than destroy.

Comment: @RichardChambers I changed "resource" to "handle" to make it clear that the handle is what is destroyed, not the file itself.

Comment: I'd actually love to see it play some music.

Comment: @JesseJ ...you mean *hear* it? ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you really need to use delete, you can use some wrappers around these constructs. Like,

```
class MyFILE
{
public:
    MyFILE(/*file params*/);
    virtual ~MyFILE(){fclose(_fileptr);
private:
    FILE * _fileptr;
}
```

A sample usage would be,

```
MyFILE * f = new MyFILE(/*file params*/);
delete f;
```

Personally, I prefer this wrapper solution, since it provides a comprehensive way to manage resources. For an example, when we on a code segment where exceptions can be thrown any time by any part of it. If we have allocated resources like open files, this mechanism opens up way to 'automatically' delete the object when the wrapper goes it out of the scope.

Comment: Of course, if we are looking for a C++ way to do this we would be using `std::ofstream`, or at a very minimum we could provide `struct file_deleter { operator()(FILE * f) { fclose(f); } }` and then we could use `std::unique_ptr<FILE, file_deleter> f {fopen(...)};` instead of creating a new type.

Comment: @cdhowie I agree. I just wanted to mention the idea Resource Acquisition Is Initialization and how it could be used. If we are up to think about the 'resource' as a 'file', yes we have couple of methods to easy or shorter methods to achieve this. On the other hand, for an example, if we need to think about net socket descriptor, still this concept works. I mean generally it works though we have simpler versions for specific cases.